# Me gustaría actualizar el titulo de unos datos dependiendo del día del mes

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta que si el día del mes es igual o mayor al día 10 del mes en curso me muestra los datos de ese mes y si el día del mes es menor al día 10 entonces me muestra los datos del mes anterior.

Lo que quiero es que si el día del mes es igual o mayor al día 10 entonces que en ese caso el titulo de ese dato me ponga el nombre del mes en curso y si el día es menor a 10 entonces que me actualice el titulo poniendo el nombre del mes anterior.

```
SELECT 26,ROUND(ISNULL(convert(FLOAT, SUM(A.num_ActosRealizados))/ convert(FLOAT, min(a.num_dias)), 0), 0),' ',B.ID,'CNT','S'
FROM TA_ActosIndicadoresAnnoMes a WITH (NOLOCK)
RIGHT JOIN TC_Centro b WITH(NOLOCK) ON a.cod_centro=b.cod_centro
AND cod_Indicador = 12
    AND 
    ( (
          DAY(FEC_ANNOMES) < 10 AND FEC_ANNOMES =  YEAR(DATEADD(MM, - 1, DATEADD(DD, - 1, GETDATE()))) * 100  + MONTH(DATEADD(MM, - 1, DATEADD(DD, - 1, GETDATE())))    
       )
       OR (
          DAY(FEC_ANNOMES) >= 10 AND FEC_ANNOMES = YEAR(GETDATE()) * 100 + MONTH(GETDATE())
       )
     )
GROUP BY B.ID
```

y este es el update que tengo pero no se donde incluirlo para que lo actualice con las condiciones de antes.

```
UPDATE TC_Constante set des_constante='Altas de hospitalización '+DATENAME(month, GETDATE()) 
WHERE COD_CONSTANTE=26
```

Comment: Hola Borja, nos comentas lo que quieres pero no qué te pasa. Puedes explicar qué problemas concretos te da ese codigo?  Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info en como mejorar la pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Mi problema es que no se donde meter los update para que me actualice el titulo de los indicadores con los criterios mencionados anteriormente.UPDATE TC_Constante set des_constante='Altas de hospitalización '+DATENAME(month, GETDATE()) 
WHERE COD_CONSTANTE=26  yo con este uptate actualizo el titulo para que me ponga el nombre del mes en curso pero no se donde meterlo para que lo haga.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] para añadir esa informacion y la que falta como l oque has probado y qué errores o problemas concretos tuviste. Un saludo

Comment: Buenas Borja, ¿intentas hacer un update mediente una select? si es así eso no se puede hacer y habría que hacer una función o un procedimiento almacenado. si no es así tendrías que dar un poco más de infromación

Comment: yo lo que quiero es que el titulo del indicador se actualice dinamicamente dependiendo de los criterios de antes .